# How can I check if my 4-bit adder/sub is working properly

Tags: verilog

How can I check if my 4-bit adder is working properly. If it is then it should display "OK" or if it's not then "NOT". I wrote the code and the bench test which will calculate all possible 4-bit combinations, but i don't know whether the output values are correct and I want to check it. My test bench is already displaying overflow. Here is my code :

```
module ripple_carry_adder_subtractor(S, C, V, A, B, Op);
   output [3:0] S;   // The 4-bit sum/difference.
   output   C;   // The 1-bit carry/borrow status.
   output   V;   // The 1-bit overflow status.
   input [3:0]  A;   // The 4-bit augend/minuend.
   input [3:0]  B;   // The 4-bit addend/subtrahend.
   input    Op;  // The operation: 0 => Add, 1=>Subtract.
   
   wire     C0; // The carry out bit of fa0, the carry in bit of fa1.
   wire     C1; // The carry out bit of fa1, the carry in bit of fa2.
   wire     C2; // The carry out bit of fa2, the carry in bit of fa3.
   wire     C3; // The carry out bit of fa2, used to generate final carry/borrrow.
   
   wire     B0; // The xor'd result of B[0] and Op
   wire     B1; // The xor'd result of B[1] and Op
   wire     B2; // The xor'd result of B[2] and Op
   wire     B3; // The xor'd result of B[3] and Op

   xor(B0, B[0], Op);
   xor(B1, B[1], Op);
   xor(B2, B[2], Op);
   xor(B3, B[3], Op);
   xor(C, C3, Op);     // Carry = C3 for addition, Carry = not(C3) for subtraction.
   xor(V, C3, C2);     // If the two most significant carry output bits differ, then we have an overflow.
   
   full_adder fa0(S[0], C0, A[0], B0, Op);    // Least significant bit.
   full_adder fa1(S[1], C1, A[1], B1, C0);
   full_adder fa2(S[2], C2, A[2], B2, C1);
   full_adder fa3(S[3], C3, A[3], B3, C2);    // Most significant bit.
endmodule // ripple_carry_adder_subtractor
```

```
module full_adder(S, Cout, A, B, Cin);
   output S;
   output Cout;
   input  A;
   input  B;
   input  Cin;
   
   wire   w1;
   wire   w2;
   wire   w3;
   wire   w4;
   
   xor(w1, A, B);
   xor(S, Cin, w1);
   and(w2, A, B);   
   and(w3, A, Cin);
   and(w4, B, Cin);   
   or(Cout, w2, w3, w4);
endmodule // full_adder
```

```
 module tb_U2_add_sub;

    reg [3:0] A;
    reg [3:0] B;
    wire [3:0] S;
    reg Op;
    wire  V;
    integer i, j;

    ripple_carry_adder_subtractor U2AS(.A(A), .B(B), .S(S), .Op(Op), .V(V));

        always @* if (V == 1) $display($time, " overflow"); 
    
        initial begin
            Op = 0; // Op = 0 ->adder; Op = 1 ->subtractor
            for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin 
                for (j=0; j<16; j=j+1) begin
                    A = i;
                    B = j;
                    #10;
                end
            end
        end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate expected values at testbench and compare them with calculated results from your module. If they are not same, you will now there is an error. In your case,

```
module tb_U2_add_sub;

    reg [3:0] A;
    reg [3:0] B;
    wire [3:0] S;
    reg Op;
    wire  V;

   integer i, j;

   ripple_carry_adder_subtractor U2AS(.A(A), .B(B), .S(S), .Op(Op), .V(V));

    reg [3:0] S_exp; // expected S value
    reg V_exp;       // expected V value

    initial begin
        Op = 0; // Op = 0 ->adder; Op = 1 ->subtractor
        for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin 
            for (j=0; j<16; j=j+1) begin
                A = i;
                B = j;
                // Calculate expected values
                S_exp = i+j;
                V_exp = (A[3]&B[3]&(~S_exp[3])) | ((~A[3])&(~B[3])&S_exp[3]);
                #10;
                // Compare expected values with calculated values
                if ((S_exp[3:0] !== S) || (V_exp !== V)) begin
                    // if there is an error, display it and stop simulation
                    $display("Failed for A=%d,B=%d.\n",A,B);
                    $stop();
                end
                    
            end
        end
        // if there is no error, you will see "Passed"
        $display("Passed");
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: it works for adding, but what about subtractracting ?